# Open a new form by reading comboBox value

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I'm not very versed in coding, let's say this is some kind of project I started without knowing anything about coding.

I have a Button which should read the selection in the comboBox and then open a specific form.
I've tried using following the **switch (comboBox1.SelectedText)**
While that didn't quite work, I tried another approach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace The_Liberion_Magnicite
{
    public partial class Form1 : The_Liberion_Magnicite.Character
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                  comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();

            {     if (comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() == "Shiroichi Kazami (PTS)")
                 {
                    this.Hide();
                    Shiro1 CShiro1 = new Shiro1();
                    CShiro1.Show();
                 }

                 else if (comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() == "Shiroichi Kazami (ATS)")

                 {   
                     this.Hide();
                     Shiro2 CShiro2 = new Shiro2();
                     CShiro2.Show();
                 }
                 else if (comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() == "Akari Hondo")

                 {
                    this.Hide();
                    AkariHondo CAkari = new AkariHondo();
                    CAkari.Show();
                 }

                 else if (comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() == "Aboa Sekihara")
                 {  
                    this.Hide();
                    AobaSeki CAoba = new AobaSeki();
                    CAoba.Show();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm in some dire need for help ;)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that when I run the whole thing, clicking the button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Modify `comboBox1.SelectedText` to `comboBox1.Text`.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it seems to work just fine. 
I'll have to look up the difference between SelectedText and Text.

Thanks a lot Kyle.